# Merge two CSV files into one with pandas by ID

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have been trying to find a solution to this all day. Read at least a dozen of the posts on this subject but nothing seems to work.

I have two csv files that I need to merge by ID. Both files have two columns with the same name: Org ID and Org Name. Below is my code:

First File

```
name_cols = ['GUID1', 'GUID2', 'Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Org Type', 'Chapter', 'Join Date', 'Effective Date', 'Expire Date']
pull_cols = ['Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Org Type', 'Chapter', 'Join Date', 'Effective Date','Expire Date']

df1 = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=name_cols, usecols=pull_cols, index_col='Org ID')
```

Second File

```
name_cols = ['GUID1', 'Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Transaction Date', 'Product Name', 'Sales Price', 'Invoice Code', 'Payment Amount', 'Add Date']
pull_cols = ['Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Transaction Date', 'Product Name', 'Sales Price', 'Invoice Code', 'Payment Amount', 'Add Date']

df2 = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=name_cols, usecols=pull_cols, index_col='Org ID')
```

I am still exploring pandas and any clues to how I should approach this would be much appriciated.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['Org ID',  'Org Name'])`? `how=` can be changed to whatever join type you please, between "inner", "left", "right", and "outer".

Comment: @cmaher Yes. that was my first go to but I got: KeyError: 'Org ID'

Comment: KeyError tells you that the key isn't in your DataFrame(s). I suggest you check that `df1` and `df2` imported as you expected. Also, you should always post what you've already tried so comments/answers are as productive as possible.

Comment: @cmaher Thanks. When I run the df1.head() and df2.head() I do get the output of all data with Org ID included. I am looking at both outputs in my Jupyter notebook file and can see both tables with data.

Comment: And you can access the `Org ID` column from both DataFrames with `df1['Org ID']` syntax?

Comment: could you share the print of: mydict = df.head(1).to_dict()

Comment: @cmaher That comes back with the same KeyError. Am I not setting my data frames up correctly? i can clearly read and manipulate both files and see all of the columns and rows.

Comment: try r"Org ID" and u"Org ID" , that is r and u

Comment: @AntonvBR {'Chapter': {'000014344O': 'Division'},
 'Effective Date': {'000014344O': '7/1/2017 0:00'},
 'Expire Date': {'000014344O': '6/30/2018 0:00'},
 'Join Date': {'000014344O': '3/16/2012 0:00'},
 'Org Name': {'000014344O': 'IABS - Headquarters'},
 'Org Type': {'000014344O': 'Supplier'}}

Comment: @user3088202 there is no "Org ID" in that dict

Comment: @AntonvBR could it be because of index_col='Org ID'? i just took it out and df1.["Org ID"] outputs all of the ids but when I try to merge I still get the same key error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149058/discussion-between-anton-vbr-and-user3088202).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussion in chat the main issue was "Org Id" being read as index. Adding param "index_col = False" did the trick:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=name_cols, usecols=pull_cols, index_col='Org ID')
```

What was then left was to do an "inner" join:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['Org ID', 'Org Name'])
```