# Finding common values between two csv file

Tags: python, csv, compare

I have two csv files (say, a and b) and both contain different datasets. The only common between those two CSV files is id_no. I would like to create a final csv file that contains all the datasets of both CSV files whose id_no are matching.

`a` looks like

```
id_no   a1    a2     a3    a4
1       0.5  0.2    0.1    10.20
2       1.5  0.1    0.2    11.25
3       2.5  0.7    0.3    12.90
4       3.5  0.8    0.4    13.19
5       7.5  0.6    0.3    14.21
```

`b` looks like

```
id_no   A1         
6       10.1  
8       2.5 
4       12.5  
2       20.5  
1       2.51
```

I am looking for a final csv file, say `c` that shows the following output

```
id_no   a1    a2     a3    a4       A1
1       0.5  0.2    0.1    10.20    2.51
2       1.5  0.1    0.2    11.25    20.5
3       2.5  0.7    0.3    12.90     0
4       3.5  0.8    0.4    13.19    12.5
5       7.5  0.6    0.3    14.21     0
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068584/merge-two-csv-files-into-one-with-pandas-by-id

Comment: you need `inner join` on id column.  check https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("data1.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("data2.csv")

output = a.merge(b, on="id_no", how="left").fillna(0).set_index("id_no")
output.to_csv("output.csv")

>>> output
        a1   a2   a3     a4     A1
id_no                             
1      0.5  0.2  0.1  10.20   2.51
2      1.5  0.1  0.2  11.25  20.50
3      2.5  0.7  0.3  12.90   0.00
4      3.5  0.8  0.4  13.19  12.50
5      7.5  0.6  0.3  14.21   0.00
```

Comment: I admit that for once, pandas is more readable than doing it by hand....

Comment: I wouldn't agree with the "for once" haha

Answer (score 0):

Using plain old python:

```py
from csv import reader, writer
from pathlib import Path


with Path("file2.csv").open as f:
    r = reader(f)
    header = next(r)
    data = {k:v for row in r for k, v in [row]}

rows = []
with Path("file1.csv").open() as f:
    r = reader(f)
    header.append(next(r)[-1])
    for i, *row in r:
        if i in data:
            rows.append([i] + row + data[i])
        else:
            rows.append([i] + row + [0])

with Path("file1.csv").open("w") as f:
    w = writer(f)
    w.write_row(header)
    w.write_rows(rows)
```

Comment: This uses lots of lines of codes as compared to another ones.

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath I gaurantee it uses few lines of code than pandas does to do the same thing ;)  but yes, it's there for completeness: it's worth knowing how to do this kind of thing by hand.  If you're using pandas for everything else, you might as well use pandas for this with the nice one-liner above.